# asp.net mvc insert doesnt seem to work for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, insert

My controller's call to repository insert method all the values are passed but it doesn't get inserted in my table..

My controller method,

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                MaterialsObj materialsObj = new MaterialsObj();
                materialsObj.Mat_Name = collection["Mat_Name"];
                materialsObj.Mes_Id = Convert.ToInt64(collection["MeasurementType"]);
                materialsObj.Mes_Name = collection["Mat_Type"];
                materialsObj.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                materialsObj.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt64(1);
                materialsObj.IsDeleted = Convert.ToInt64(1);
                consRepository.createMaterials(materialsObj);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

and my repository,

```
public MaterialsObj createMaterials(MaterialsObj materialsObj)
{
    Material mat = new Material();
    mat.Mat_Name = materialsObj.Mat_Name;
    mat.Mat_Type = materialsObj.Mes_Name;
    mat.MeasurementTypeId = materialsObj.Mes_Id;
    mat.Created_Date = materialsObj.CreatedDate;
    mat.Created_By = materialsObj.CreatedBy;
    mat.Is_Deleted = materialsObj.IsDeleted;
    db.Materials.InsertOnSubmit(mat);
    return materialsObj;
}
```

What am i missing here any suggestion....

Comment: BTW, when you get bored of writing `mat.Mat_Name = materialsObj.Mat_Name;`, take a look at Automapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're missing a `db.SubmitChanges();` to save to the database.

Comment: @Chris oh god how did i miss that!

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Materials.InsertOnSubmit(mat);
db.SubmitChanges(); // <---------------
return materialsObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing a call to `SubmitChanges`?

```
db.Materials.InsertOnSubmit(mat);
db.SubmitChanges();
```